# How can I disable changing view to cursor upon typing in VS Code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, text-editing

Typing while the cursor is not on screen causes the view to scroll back to the cursor, I could not find anything in VS Code's settings nor could I find any information online on how to change this behaviour.

I want to look to another part of my code as reference while writing something else.

I am using macOS 13.2 and VS Code 1.75.1.

Does anyone know how to disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be seen as an XY problem. If you want to edit one part of an open editor while looking at another part of the open editor, then you can use the split panels / [editor groups](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_editor-groups) feature of VS Code.

There's a horizontal split button at the top right of the workbench ([image]/[image]), and various command palette commands with "split" in their names. You can also use the menu: `View > Editor Layout > <direction>...`. The split will create a new editor group containing an editor for the split, which can be independently scrolled.